# Duplicating script and incrementing id names to dynamically add input content

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, if-statement

I am currently working on a website to easily modify css properties and animate using jquery. The page will then output the code for the user to copy and paste into their work.

I am wanting to dynamically add input fields so users can enter their own parameters in "keyframes" for the animation.

I was wondering if there is a way to have a button to create the new elements and the jquery to have it operate. Currently I have tried setting a variables value to increment with the button then have a "for" loop to create the new keyframe elements.

Is there a way to append the previous keyframes with new keyframes

this is a sample of the things I need to set when creating the DOM nodes for the input fields, but the main issue I am having is incrementing the value of "i" and duplicating the code only once.

//////////TOP TEXT INPUT///////////

```
    var newTop = document.createElement('input')

    newTop.type = "text"
    newTop.id ="animation_" + i + "_top" // i = 1
    newTop.size="10" 
    newTop.value="100" 
    newTop.name="animation_" + i +"_top" // i = 1
    newTop.textContent = "top";

    var refTopSibling = document.getElementById('frame_1')
    var refTopParent = refTopSibling.parentNode

    refTopParent.appendChild(newTop)
```

//////////TOP TEXT INPUT///////////

```
    var newLeft = document.createElement('input')

    newLeft.type = "text"
    newLeft.id ="animation_" + i + "_left" // i = 2
    newLeft.size="10" 
    newLeft.value="100" 
    newLeft.name="animation_" + i +"_left" // i = 2
    newLeft.textContent = "left";


    var refTopSibling = document.getElementById("animation_" + i + "_top")
    var refTopParent = refTopSibling.parentNode

    refTopParent.appendChild(newLeft)
```

Regards,

Andrew

EDIT--------------------------

Thanks for the replies. Unfotunately it's a little large for JS fiddle. I'm only a noob so this may not be the most elegant way to do it, but I used an if statement to increment the variables current value on each press... unfortunately it's not dynamic but I have enough options to allow 11 keyframes of animation that can be dynamically added to the DOM.

function addFrame(){

```
var n;

if (document.getElementById('frame_1')){n=2};
if (document.getElementById('frame_2')){n=3};
if (document.getElementById('frame_3')){n=4};
if (document.getElementById('frame_4')){n=5};
if (document.getElementById('frame_5')){n=6};
if (document.getElementById('frame_6')){n=7};
if (document.getElementById('frame_7')){n=8};
if (document.getElementById('frame_8')){n=9};
if (document.getElementById('frame_9')){n=10};
if (document.getElementById('frame_10')){n=11};
```

//rest of the code here

}

Now to figure out a way to draw svg dynamically and animate it with user inputs ;-)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so that it can be worked on.??

Comment: Are you wanting i to be shared between the lefts and the tops?  Is the problem that you don't want to duplicate all of the code?

Comment: Why not just a class name for all the common CSS and then use the dynamic for of `.on()` with a class name for any event handlers?

Comment: So you just need to know how to structure the `for` statement to properly iterate, and how to perform a piece of code only once during an iteration/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the best implementation but I believe it meets your requirements.

```
function SampleObject(position, i)
{
    this.posString = "new" + position;
    $(this[this.posString] = document.createElement("input"))
            .css({  type: "text",
                    id: "animation_" + i + "_" + position,
                    size: "10" ,
                    value: "100" ,
                    name: "animation_" + i +"_" + position,
                    textContent: position
                });

    $("#frame_1").parent().append(el);
}

//Public methods
SampleObject.prototype.getInput = function()
{
    return this[this.posString];
}
//Static members
SampleObject.set = [];

//Static methods
SampleObject.new = function(position);
{
    this.set.push(new SampleObject(position, this.set.length + 1));
}

//Quick test
SampleObject.new("top");
```

jQuery rewrite aside this does three actions, albeit the last might be surplus to requirement.

1) Rather than write a new function for every position the constructor of the object takes a position string (any string would be fine but for your objective position seems apt). The string is appended to "new" to form the "new" that is used to create an object member named in accordance with the current multi-function approach in the post that stores the new input object - personally I think the member naming is redundant but I don't know the project.  The object has a get method for returning the input form.

2) Using the static "Sample.new" method (which takes a position parameter) a new SampleObject  which has an index value of 1 + (static member) SampleObject.set, the set variable is used to store the new objects as they are created. This might not be necessary but I imagine you'll want to interact with them later or attach event.

As for the "frame_" if statements

```
$("[id^=frame_]").length() + 1
```

Assuming that frames are always created iteratively this will return the appropriate value for n.